# How can I implement a 'category filter' in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, masonry, jquery-isotope

## Scenario

In an Angular2 app, I have some code in a component's view `parent.component.html` looping through an array of `items` and outputting each `item` as a new component:

```
<div class="list-items">
  <!-- In the attached image, this is displayed as a coloured card -->
  <app-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></app-list-slide>
</div>
```

Each `item` has a `category` key which is an array of ids (corresponding to the id of each category in a separate list).

```
// Item JSON
[
  { 
    "id": 1,
    "imageUrl": "https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=1",
    "title": "One",
    "categories": [ 1 ]
  }
]

// Category JSON
[
  { "id": 1, "title": "Red Cards" },
  { "id": 2, "title": "Blue Cards" }
]
```

## Requirement

The app needs to have a filter, dynamically generated by the categories (I might make this into a separate component):

```
<div class="items-filter">
  <!-- In the attached image, this is displayed as a list of category buttons -->
  <div *ngFor="let category of categories">
    <a (click)="filterItemsByCategory(category)">{{ category.title }}</a>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-o">Reset</div>
</div>
```

When a category item is clicked, only the items corresponding to that category should be shown. Ideally, multiple categories could be clicked, but that can be for later.

All the examples I can find for filters, seem to use text input based filtering, and I'm not really sure where to start with this.

Final product should look like this:
[image: end product]

## Similar Example

Here is an example of something very similar to what I am trying to do (but the text input box would be replaced with the array of category buttons):

Article:
http://www.freakyjolly.com/angular-4-5-typescript-create-filter-list-with-check-boxes-to-select-from-list/

Demo:
https://freakyjolly.com/demo/AngularJS/Angular5FilterList/

## Question

My question is either, does anyone know of any good working examples of what I am trying to do, or can anyone suggest a good place to start with this?

One option I can think of is to create classes on the component corresponding to the ids of the categories `class="category-1 category-2"` but this seems messy.

Another option is using something like Masonary or Isotope, but a lot of the Angular libraries for these seem to be outdated: https://github.com/search?q=angular+masonry

Thanks

Comment: The angular team recommends to not use pipes for filtering or sorting, just filter in the component/service. https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe . That being said you need to clarify what your data looks like, what the input to the filter function looks like and what you expect the results to look like after filtering/transformation. A workable example through StackBlitz would go a long way to assist you.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have added some json and an image, the json really is pretty small, and the final product is pretty simple, but I can make a StackBlitz should it be needed. Thanks again

Comment: Can you share the json for an item(s)?

Comment: Have updated the JSON in the question for categories and items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by create a new variable, an array representing the filtered items and using `*ngFor` with those filtered items. You'd use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Array.prototype.includes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to filter items based on whether the id of the category is included in the item's categories array of id values:

Component:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { Item } from "./item.ts";
import { Category } from "./category.ts";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  items: Item[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      imageUrl: "https://via.placeholder.com/300x150/FF0000/FFFFFF?text=1",
      title: "One",
      categories: [1]
    }
  ];
  categories: Category[] = [
    { id: 1, title: "Red Cards" },
    { id: 2, title: "Blue Cards" }
  ];
  // Create a shallow copy of the items array
  filteredItems: Item[] = [...this.items];

  filterItemsByCategory(category: Category) {
    this.filteredItems = this.items.filter((item: Item) => {
      return item.categories.includes(category.id);
    })
  }

  reset() {
    this.filteredItems = [...this.items];
  }
}
```

Template:

```
<div class="items-filter">
    <!-- In the attached image, this is displayed as a list of category buttons -->
    <div *ngFor="let category of categories">
        <button type="button" (click)="filterItemsByCategory(category)">{{ category.title }}</button>
    </div>
    <button type="button" (click)="reset()" class="btn-o">Reset</button>
</div>

<div class="list-items">
    <!-- In the attached image, this is displayed as a coloured card -->
    <app-item *ngFor="let item of filteredItems" [item]="item">
    </app-item>
</div>
```

Here is an example in [action](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxzfbt). If your date is async, which it most likely is in your actual application, you can use `*ngIf` and/or defaults to empty arrays `[]` to avoid trying to perform array operations on undefined/null.

Also, it's recommend to avoid using `<a>` elements as buttons, and instead just use `<button>` elements. Also, as mentioned in a comment, the [angular team recommends NOT using pipes for filtering and/or sorting](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe), so I'd avoid doing what the articles you link suggest.

Comment: What a wiz! Thank you so much, this is so helpful, and hopefully will be to others searching for similar too.